# Is there a Groovy simpleTemplateEngine silent tag?

Tags: templates, groovy

Is there a silent tag for groovy simpleTemplateEngine, if not perhaps another template engine?

What I am looking for is a tag which does not print a new line for `if` statements like `<%- -%>` for ERB in Ruby.

Take a look at the code below:

```
import groovy.text.*

def binding = ['Foo':'Bar']

def template = """
<% if(true){ %>
<%= Foo %>
<% } %>
"""

def rendered = new SimpleTemplateEngine(true).
                      createTemplate(template).
                      make(binding).
                      toString()

print rendered
```

Because it's running in debug mode it prints the source code for the parsed template, we can see that it's printing a new line before and after the desired output:

```
-- script source --
out.print("""
"""); if(true){ ;
out.print("""
${ Foo }
"""); } ;
out.print("""
""");

/* Generated by SimpleTemplateEngine */
-- script end --
```

I obviously already tried `<%- -%>` but I've got a syntax error :(

Comment: I assume putting `<% if(true){ %><%= Foo %><% } %>` on one line isn't good enough?

Comment: @tim_yates yeah, that's just a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not the real problem. What I am looking for is a silent tag or perhaps another template engine.